# Select gateway used for certain commands on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have multiple network interfaces providing a connection to the internet. I can change the interface used for internet access via `route add default gw ...` at any time.

However, is it possible to select the gateway for a certain command only? For example have one process use a GSM modem link, while the system uses the ethernet link for all other internet requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can to that with `iptables` and a different user. Assuming that the IP address of the interface you want the command to use, is `1.2.3.4` and the name `eth1` and the gateway `1.2.3.1`.

1) Create a new user:

```
adduser user2
```

2) Mark packets coming from that user:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner user2 -j MARK --set-mark 42
```

3) Apply the IP address on those packages:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -m mark --mark 42 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

4) Route marked packets via `eth1`'s gateway:

```
ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42
ip route add default via 1.2.3.1 dev eth1 table 42
```

5) Execute the command as the new user:

```
sudo -u user2 ping example.com
```

`ping example.com` would now be routed over the gateway `1.2.3.1` not the systems default gateway.

Comment: Ugh, kinda laborious. Nevertheless, I will try it out these days.